# При использовании XMLHttpRequest не отправляются данные на сервлет

Tags: java, ajax, servlet, tomcat, xmlhttprequest

Хочу, для дальнейшего использования AJAX, отправить данные из формы в сервлет для проверки, однако при выводе:*System.out.println(request.getAttribute("name"))*, получаю всегда null. Также при нажатии на send страница просто перезагружается. При использовании *action="controller"* request со всеми полями улетает на сервлет и генерится новая страница. Tomcat 9.0.14

Буду благодарен любым идеям!!!

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код формы:

```
  <form name="myform" method="POST" onsubmit="load()" action="" id="change">
     <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="input-group ">
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              </br><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" value="anton"/>
              <br/>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row ">
        <div class="input-group ">
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон " name="number" value="123"/>
              <br/>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row ">
        <div class="input-group ">
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш email (не обязательно) " name="email" value="@"/>
              <br/>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
           <div class="input-group ">
              <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder=" Ваш комментарий"name="comment" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
           <div class="input-group mt-2">
              <input  type="submit" onclick=" load();"  value="send">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Код сервлета:

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FormController extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getAttribute("name"));

       String text = "<h2> your form is in process</h2>";
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().write(text);


    }
}
```

js:

```
 function load() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST','file');
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    xhttp.send("name=" + name);
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.FormController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено:

Добавил в *js*, убрал из формы все *onsubmit* и *onclick*, и в сервлет *request.getAttribute()* заменил *request.getParameter()*

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let form = document.querySelector("#change");
    form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        let p = new URLSearchParams();
        p.append('name', 'lel');

        fetch("file", {
            headers: {
                'Accept': '*/*'
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: p
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.trace(error);
        });
    });
});
```